# How to find all elements that DON'T have specific CSS class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to get all form elements that don't have a specific CSS class.
Example:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="good"/>
    <input type="text" class="good"/>
    <input type="text" class="bad"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

What selector should I use to select all elements that don't have 'bad' css class?

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the not() filter:

```
$("input").not(".bad")
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the [not selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not):

```
$('input:not(".bad")').hide();
```

Note the quotes are not needed:

```
$('input:not(.bad)').hide();
```

See:

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not

Comment: The quotes around .bad in the :not selector aren't needed

Comment: @Russ Cam - true, added that to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("input:not(.bad)")
```